# link with post Increment and log statement in recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want my function to print sum by using recursion

```
function sumOf(num){
        if(num == 1 ) return 1;
         console.log("we are seeing decrement",num--)
        return num + sumOf(num--);
    }
    console.log(sumOf(6))
```

## output:-

```
we are seeing decrement 6
we are seeing decrement 5
we are seeing decrement 4
we are seeing decrement 3
we are seeing decrement 2
16
```

I am getting wrong output why ?

**correct-Output :- 21**

```
function sumOf(num){
    if(num == 1 ) return 1;
    return num + sumOf(num--);
}
console.log(sumOf(6))
```

**output:-**

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
     at sumOf (C:\Users\mdvenkat\Desktop\dataStructures and algortherms\recurssion_2.js:4:18)
        at sumOf (C:\Users\mdvenkat\Desktop\dataStructures and algortherms\recurssion_2.js:4:18)
        at sumOf (C:\Users\mdvenkat\Desktop\dataStructures and algortherms\recurssion_2.js:4:18)
        at sumOf (C:\Users\mdvenkat\Desktop\dataStructures and algortherms\recurssion_2.js:4:18)
        at sumOf (C:\Users\mdvenkat\Desktop\dataStructures and algortherms\recurssion_2.js:4:18)
        at sumOf (C:\Users\mdvenkat\Desktop\dataStructures and algortherms\recurssion_2.js:4:18)
        at sumOf (C:\Users\mdvenkat\Desktop\dataStructures and algortherms\recurssion_2.js:4:18)
```

Why Now i am getting RangeError ,is there any Link between log statement and recursion

**Note:- i came to know if we change num-- to num-1 it will work but i want the reason for following error (same code but only removed console log)**

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's working as expected.

```js
function sumOf(num){
        if(num == 1 ) return 1;
         console.log("we are seeing decrement",num--)
        return num + sumOf(num--);
    }
    console.log(sumOf(6))
```

The case in which it's not working is when when you're calling `sumOf(num--)`

It works like this : first the `num` is returned and then it's decremented. So It keeps calling `6` recursively. 6 is never cleared from the stack.

```
//sumOf(6) //doesn't matter what you do with num-- now, sumOf(6) has already been called
//calls sum(6) again due to the previous execution
//calls sumOf(6) again and it keeps happening ...
```

What you're doing with console is you're decrementing with `num--`. So if you just do this, that will work too.

```js
    function sumOf(num){
            if(num == 1 )return 1;
             num--;
             return num + sumOf(num);
            
        }
        console.log(sumOf(6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this. You are using post decrement operator ,else use pre decrement operator

```
function sumOf(num){
    if(num === 1 ) return 1;
    return num + sumOf(--num);
}
console.log(sumOf(6))
```

Comment: it went to infinite loop because num is not getting decremented and since recursion uses stack , hence stack got exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it makes a difference is because n-- (unlike --n or n-1) returns the value before decrementing.

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x--), the
>   decrement operator decrements and returns the value before
>   decrementing.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement